# Why does my Python method continue after the return statement is called?

Tags: python, recursion

When executing the following method, it runs correctly until it gets to a point where it hits the first return statement where it returns the path. At that point, it does not exit the method, but jumps to the second to last line where the method is then invoked again, causing infinite recursion. Shouldn't the method automatically exit once return is called?

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python degrees.py [directory]")
    directory = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else "small"

    # Load data from files into memory
    print("Loading data...")
    load_data(directory)
    print("Data loaded.")

    source = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if source is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")
    target = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if target is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")

    path = shortest_path(source, source, target, set(), list())

    if path is None:
        print("Not connected.")
    else:
        degrees = len(path)
        print(f"{degrees} degrees of separation.")
        path = [(None, source)] + path
        print(path)


def shortest_path(original, source, target, visitedpeople=set(), path=list()):
    """
    Returns the shortest list of person_id
    that connect the source to the target.

    If no possible path, returns None.
    """
    if source == target:
        return []
    while source != target:
        destinations = neighbors_for_person(source)
        visitedpeople.add(source)
        neighbors = list()
        for x in range(len(destinations)):
            neighbors.append(destinations[x])
        if neighbors.__contains__(target):
            for neighbor in destinations:
                if neighbor == target:
                    path.append(neighbor)
            return path
        else:
            if all(x in visitedpeople for x in neighbors):
                shortest_path(original, original, target, visitedpeople, path)
            else:
                for neighbor in destinations:
                    if neighbor not in visitedpeople:
                        path.append(neighbor)
                        visitedpeople.add(neighbor)
                        shortest_path(original, neighbor, target, visitedpeople, path)
    return []
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that invokes this function?

Comment: A function will always exit when it reaches a return. There must be something else going on. You're probably seeing a previous recursive call finishing because you aren't returning the result of the recursive calls.

Comment: I think you have a misconception that when a recursive function returns, it causes the original call to return too. That is not the case. I have [an interactive model which shows how recursive functions execute](https://werp.site/cs-toys/recursion.html), which might help you to understand what's happening with some simpler examples - when a recursive call returns, the value it returns goes to the call above it in the call stack, and that call then resumes.

Comment: Do not take mutable values as default arguments. I don't think this is the problem you're seeing, but that list and set as arguments are getting reused in subsequent calls to the default argument. See: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/